# How to use ldapsearch on a Domain Name instead of a specific host

Tags: bash, ldap

I have a bash script that runs ldapsearch with no problems except it points to a DC that is sometimes not available.

The script uses a -h (for host) option to point to a specific Domain Controller (DC). I would like to point to the domain name instead so that it will still execute in case that particular DC is down.

Example

In our environment, we have 20 DC's under my.company.com. So my ldapsearch query uses the the 1st DC in Bldg 1 with the following option which works:

```
-H ldaps://bldg1dc01.my.company.com:636
```

If bldg1dc01 is down, the script will not execute. So I'd like to point the script to something like:

```
-H ldaps://my.company.com:636
```

But when I do that, I get:

```
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

What is the syntax to query the domain name (my.company.com) instead of the specific DC, that way my script works even if that DC is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT :

After further researches, I looked at the `ldapsearch` command as I did not know the possibility to provide multiple URI.

The man states (for the `ldap-utils` package command) :

> Specify URI(s) referring to the ldap server(s); a list of URI,
>   separated by whitespace or commas is expected; only the
>   protocol/host/port fields are allowed. As an exception, if no
>   host/port is specified, but a DN is, the DN is used to look up the
>   corresponding host(s) using the DNS SRV records, according to RFC
>   2782. The DN must be a non-empty sequence of AVAs whose attribute type is "dc" (domain component), and must be escaped according to RFC 2396.

So there is the possibility to use DNS result to make the `ldapsearch`.

Example with `google.com` :

```
#  dig -t srv _ldaps._tcp.google.com +short
5 0 636 ldap.google.com.
```

So if I do the search with (escaping the URI) :

```
# ldapsearch -H ldaps:///dc%3Dgoogle%2Cdc%3Dcom -v
ldap_initialize( ldaps://ldap.google.com:636 )
^C
```

So the command is able to look for DNS SRV records

My bad asserting what I believed was the only way to do it without further research

---

Not relevant, but the informations could be used in case no DNS reccords is available

*There is no problem with your syntax. This is a misunderstanding of what the `ldapsearch` does and what LDAP is.*

LDAP is a protocol, `ldapsearch` command is a client which communicates implementing this protocol.

It is the same as saying I try to connect to `https://my.company.com` on port `443` and it doesn't work, but when I do it on `https://web01.my.company.com` it works.

You need to have something listening on port 443 on `my.company.com` and load-balances/proxies the requests.

It is the same for LDAP.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was hoping the ldapsearch had some sort of dns implementation in it. 

Example, when I open powershell and perform an nslookup on my.company.com I get the same if I did it on google.com, a list of computer IPs. I was hoping that ldapsearch would inherently resolve the domain name and use the list results as an array to use for its connection. 

I have found an alternate solution for now. I'm using a comma separated list of all 20 domain controllers for the -H argument which behaves very well.

Comment: @scryptKiddy I edited my answer. After more research, I was wrong and it is possible to lookup in DNS SRV reccords. I edited my aswer accordingly. My bad I answered to haslty

Comment: No worries, and thanks for the followup, this is what I was looking for, thanks for the explanation too!